# Click event not fired within drop down

Tags: reactjs, reactstrap

Created a working sample:
https://codesandbox.io/s/collapse-gmqpp

The problem was I had a map function, so multiple dropdown. So I needed to handle multiple states. One for each dropdown. So I ended up adding a property on the media object I could toggle on. Thanks everybody for input.

I have a really strange problem hope somebody can help as I am new to REACT. I know it is a big chunk of code , but below is the summary of the problem. Click events outside the DropDown tag wrapped in a div works. However the click events within the dropdown does not work? They are simply not fired.

```
<div> THIS WORKS!
  <DropdownItem
    onClick={() => toggleCrawlResultModal("")}
  >
    Result
  </DropdownItem>
  <DropdownItem onClick={() => alert("dd")}>
    Analytics
  </DropdownItem>
  <DropdownItem onClick={toggleAIModal}>
    Insights
  </DropdownItem>
  <DropdownItem onClick={toggleDetails}>
    Details
  </DropdownItem>
</div>

 CLICK EVENTS BELOW DOES NOT WORK
<Dropdown toggle={toggleMenu} isOpen={dropdownOpen}>
  <DropdownToggle tag="div">
    &bull;&bull;&bull;
  </DropdownToggle>
  <DropdownMenu>
    <DropdownItem
      onClick={() => toggleCrawlResultModal("")}
    >
      Result
    </DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem onClick={() => alert("dd")}>
      Analytics
    </DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem onClick={toggleAIModal}>
      Insights
    </DropdownItem>
    <DropdownItem onClick={toggleDetails}>
      Details
    </DropdownItem>
  </DropdownMenu>
</Dropdown>
```

If I change the events in the dropdown to use arrow functions, then the events work. However then they are triggered on page load on not when clicking the toggle button:

```
<Dropdown toggle={() => toggleMenu()} isOpen={() => dropdownOpen()}>
```

More tests:
If I do the following events works, however the dropdown is always expanded:

```
<Dropdown isOpen={true}>
```

It is like the way I do it, toggle eat's all the events from child elements within the dropdown element.

I succeeded making a really bad sample on codesandbox. Click the 3 dots and then click on the Results button. It has same behaviour:

https://codesandbox.io/s/collapse-gmqpp?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Complete code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import DropdownPaging from "./DropdownPaging";
import TimeBar from "./TimeBar";
import { CrawlService } from "../../services/CrawlService";
import {
  Card,
  CardBody,
  CardHeader,
  Collapse,
  Fade,
  Row,
  Col,
  InputGroup,
  InputGroupAddon,
  Button,
  Input,
  DropdownItem,
  DropdownMenu,
  Dropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  Modal,
  ModalBody,
  ModalHeader
} from "reactstrap";

const CrawlJobs = () => {
  const [debug, setDebug] = useState(true);

  const [timeout] = useState(300);
  const [fadeIn] = useState(true);
  const [dropdownOpen, setDropdownOpen] = useState(false);
  const [showCrawlResultModal, setShowCrawlResultModal] = useState(false);
  const [showAnalyticsModal, setShowAnalyticsModal] = useState(false);
  const [showAIModal, setShowAIModal] = useState(false);
  const [showDetailsModal, setShowDetailsModal] = useState(false);
  const [mediaList, setMediaList] = useState([]);

  const [tester, setTester] = useState(false);

  const [pageInfo, setPageInfo] = useState({
    minutes: 10,
    pageIndex: 0,
    pageSize: 10
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchMediaData = async () => {
      try {
        var mediaResult = await CrawlService.getJobs();
        setMediaList(mediaResult.data);
      } catch (error) {}
    };
    fetchMediaData();
  }, []);

  const getMediaIcon = mediaName => {
    switch (mediaName) {
      case "Facebook":
        return "fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x";
      case "Youtube":
        return "fa fa-youtube-square fa-2x";
      case "Twitter":
        return "fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x";
      case "Instagram":
        return "fa fa-instagram fa-2x";

      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  const pagerValueChanged = val => {
    setPageInfo({
      pageIndex: val.pageIndex,
      pageSize: val.take,
      minutes: pageInfo.minutes
    });
    setDebug(val.take + ", " + val.pageIndex);
  };

  const toggleDetails = e => {
    setShowDetailsModal(!showDetailsModal);
  };
  const toggleAIModal = e => {
    setShowAIModal(!showAIModal);
  };

  const toggleAnalyticsModal = e => {
    setShowAnalyticsModal(!showAnalyticsModal);
  };

  const toggleCrawlResultModal = e => {
    alert("fff");
    setShowCrawlResultModal(!showCrawlResultModal);
  };

  const toggleMenu = e => {
    setDropdownOpen(!dropdownOpen);
  };

  const test = () => {
    alert(
      "minutes:" +
        pageInfo.minutes +
        ", pageIndex:" +
        pageInfo.pageIndex +
        ", pageSize:" +
        pageInfo.pageSize
    );
  };

  const toggle = media => {
    setMediaList(
      mediaList.map(m => {
        return m.typeId === media.typeId ? { ...m, toggle: !m.toggle } : m;
      })
    );
  };

  const loadJobsTable = media => {};

  const minutesChanged = val => {
    setPageInfo({ minutes: val });
  };

  return (
    <div className="animated fadeIn">
      <Row style={{ marginBottom: 10 }}>
        <button onClick={test}>TEST</button>
        <Col xs="6" sm="6" md="6">
          <TimeBar onClick={minutesChanged}></TimeBar>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <Row>
        <Col xs="4" sm="4" md="4">
          <InputGroup>
            <InputGroupAddon addonType="prepend">
              <Button type="button" color="secondary">
                <i className="fa fa-search"></i>
              </Button>
            </InputGroupAddon>
            <Input
              type="text"
              id="input1-group2"
              name="input1-group2"
              placeholder="Tag or profile name"
            />
          </InputGroup>
        </Col>
      </Row>

      <h2>Profiles</h2>

      {mediaList.map(media => (
        <Row key={media.typeId}>
          <Col xs="12" sm="12" md="12">
            <Fade timeout={timeout} in={fadeIn}>
              <Card>
                <CardHeader style={{ padding: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
                  <table
                    className="table table-borderless"
                    style={{ marginBottom: 0, padding: 0 }}
                  >
                    <tbody>
                      <tr>
                        <td className="align-middle" style={{ width: 50 }}>
                          <i className={getMediaIcon(media.name)}></i>
                        </td>

                        {media.statusList.map(status => (
                          <td key={"statusTD" + status.statusId}>
                            <button
                              className="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block"
                              onClick={() => toggle(media)}
                            >
                              {status.name} ({status.count})
                            </button>
                          </td>
                        ))}
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
                </CardHeader>
                <Collapse isOpen={media.toggle} id="collapseExample">
                  <CardBody>
                    <table className="table table-responsive-sm table-striped">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th>Username</th>
                          <th>Date registered</th>
                          <th>Role</th>
                          <th></th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Yiorgos Avraamu</td>
                          <td>2012/01/01</td>
                          <td>Member</td>
                          <td style={{ width: 20, cursor: "pointer" }}>
                            <div>
                              <DropdownItem
                                onClick={() => toggleCrawlResultModal("")}
                              >
                                Result
                              </DropdownItem>
                              <DropdownItem onClick={() => alert("dd")}>
                                Analytics
                              </DropdownItem>
                              <DropdownItem onClick={toggleAIModal}>
                                Insights
                              </DropdownItem>
                              <DropdownItem onClick={toggleDetails}>
                                Details
                              </DropdownItem>
                            </div>

                            <Dropdown toggle={toggleMenu} isOpen={dropdownOpen}>
                              <DropdownToggle tag="div">
                                &bull;&bull;&bull;
                              </DropdownToggle>
                              <DropdownMenu>
                                <DropdownItem
                                  onClick={() => toggleCrawlResultModal("")}
                                >
                                  Result
                                </DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem onClick={() => alert("dd")}>
                                  Analytics
                                </DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem onClick={toggleAIModal}>
                                  Insights
                                </DropdownItem>
                                <DropdownItem onClick={toggleDetails}>
                                  Details
                                </DropdownItem>
                              </DropdownMenu>
                            </Dropdown>
                          </td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Avram Tarasios</td>
                          <td>2012/02/01</td>
                          <td>Staff</td>
                          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Quintin Ed</td>
                          <td>2012/02/01</td>
                          <td>Admin</td>
                          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Enéas Kwadwo</td>
                          <td>2012/03/01</td>
                          <td>Member</td>
                          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td>Agapetus Tadeáš</td>
                          <td>2012/01/21</td>
                          <td>Staff</td>
                          <td>&bull;&bull;&bull;</td>
                        </tr>
                      </tbody>
                    </table>

                    <div>
                      <p>{debug}</p>
                      <DropdownPaging
                        valueChanged={pagerValueChanged}
                      ></DropdownPaging>
                    </div>
                  </CardBody>
                </Collapse>
              </Card>
            </Fade>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      ))}

      <h2>Tags</h2>

      <div>
        <Modal
          isOpen={showCrawlResultModal}
          toggle={toggleCrawlResultModal}
          size="lg"
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={toggleCrawlResultModal}>
            Crawl Result
          </ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>TBD</ModalBody>
        </Modal>
        <Modal isOpen={showAIModal} toggle={toggleAIModal} size="lg">
          <ModalHeader toggle={toggleAIModal}>Insights</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>TBD</ModalBody>
        </Modal>
        <Modal
          isOpen={showAnalyticsModal}
          toggle={toggleAnalyticsModal}
          size="lg"
        >
          <ModalHeader toggle={toggleAnalyticsModal}>Analytics</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>TBD</ModalBody>
        </Modal>
        <Modal isOpen={showDetailsModal} toggle={toggleDetails} size="lg">
          <ModalHeader toggle={toggleDetails}>Details</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>TBD</ModalBody>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default CrawlJobs;
```

Comment: Is it possible to host this particular page in code pen. It is very hard to debug react application by just looking at the codebase.

Comment: I actually tried but I could not get it to work with react-strap etc. I had the feeling it was terrible to get through. I have some more findings that maybe could help. I will update post in 30 seconds.

Comment: use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) to share your code

Comment: Normally I actually use codesandbox. However I have another thread in here about reactstrap not working in codesandbox :D Nothing goes my way to day. I updated the original post. I think it is related to arrow functions. If I update the events on the dropdown to use arrow functions then the click event works. However no the fires on page load.

Comment: fyi here is the thread related to codesandbox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59615801/adding-reactstrap-as-dependency-to-sandbox

Comment: `dropdownOpen` is the current state, not a function. I imagine you should just be passing the bool to `isOpen` aka:  `isOpen={dropdownOpen}`

Comment: Is that not what I am allready doing? I noticed that everytime I click something wirhin the DropDown menu the toggle is triggered. It is like the DropDown eat's the event for it's children. That is why it works with the div instead of dropdown. I wonder is it is a reactstrap thing.

Comment: If I do this events works <Dropdown isOpen={true}>

Comment: I was looking at your first "test", but see it doesn't match your code in other areas. What you've described above sounds like you have overlapping buttons and could be an [issue with reactstrap](https://github.com/reactstrap/reactstrap/issues/54)?

Comment: I succeeded in making a really bad sample :D Click on the 3 dots. And then click on the results button.

Comment: It could be I had it working in a class component. After refactor to arrow function component I got this. As you can see I made a sample on codesandbox that simulates the same behavour.